# Cannot retrive NgForm.value inside ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

I have a template driven form and I have to save the initial values of controls. To do this, I supposed the **ngAfterViewInit** method was a good place, since it is called after the template is rendered and I'm sure I can "read" the value of form controls.

When I try to save the form controls value inside a variable this way:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {    
      this.initialFormValue = this.form.value;    
  }
```

I get just an empty object. The weird thing happens when I try to print the **NgForm Object** and the **initialFormValue** variable. The NgForm object has data inside the value property, but the initialFormValue is an empty object;

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {    
    if(this.form!=null){
      this.initialFormValue = this.form;
      console.dir(this.initialFormValue.value);
      console.dir(this.form);
    }
  }
```

[image]

I expected **initialFormValue** variable has the same value of NgForm.value.

Comment: Show also the html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set value, for example:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.contact = {
    firstname: "Sachin"
  }
}
```

```html
<form #contactForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm)">
  <p>
    <label for="firstname">First Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" [(ngModel)]="contact.firstname">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, thank you for the answer. Actually I know how to set a value for a FormControl. What I dont' get is how to retriveve the value of all the FormControls as soon as the forme template is rendered.

Comment: Can you add the html file?